# Stochastic domination and expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $X$ is stochastically smaller than $Y$ (both random variables of course). In addition let $X,Y\geq0$ and $g$ a smooth function with g(0)=0. Why is
$$
Eg(X)=\int_0^\infty g'(z)P(X>z)dz \leq \int_0^\infty g'(z)P(Y>z)dz=Eg(Y)
$$
I understand the inequality in the middle but is it normal to use the notation $g'(z)$ here, shouldn't it be $g(z)$?

Comment: I think you are searching for something like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222478/expectation-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable-from-cdf

Comment: Additionally, for the inequality in the middle you need that $g' \geq 0$, i.e. $g$ is non-decreasing.

Otherwise suppose $X \equiv 1$ and $Y\equiv 2$ and $g(1) = 1$ and $g(2)=0$, then your inequality is false.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, note that if $g' \ge 0$, then $g$ is non-decreasing and so $g(Y)$ dominates $g(X)$, from which it follows that $Eg(X) \le Eg(Y)$, irrespective of whether $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the OP's real question is how to get $Eg(X) = \int_0^\infty g'(z)P(X > z)$ (and analogously for $Y$).

---

Using elementary properties of integrals, one can write

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^\infty g'(z) P(X > z)dz &= \int_0^\infty g'(z)\left(\int_{z}^\infty f_X(x)dx\right)dz = \int_0^\infty\int_{z}^\infty g'(z)f_X(x)dx dz\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^xg'(z)f_X(x)dzdx = \int_{0}^\infty \left(\int_{0}^xg'(z)dz\right)f_X(x)dx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty (g(x)-g(0))f_X(x)dx = \int_{0}^\infty g(x)f_X(x) =Eg(X),
\end{split}
$$
since $f_X$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$.

---

## Edit: More general solution not assuming that $X$ has a density function!

For any $x \in \mathbb R$, one may rewrite
$$
g(x) = \int_{0}^x g'(z)dz = \int_0^\infty1_{\{x > z\}}g'(z)dz,
$$

where the 2nd equality is integration by parts, and the second is because the fucntion $z \mapsto 1_{\{x > z\}}$ is identically equal to $1$ on the interval $[0,x]$ (which might be empty!), and $0$ outside.

Thus, by the *Law of the unconscious statistician*, we may compute

$$
\begin{split}
Eg(X) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dP_X = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{0}^\infty 1_{\{x > z\}}g'(z)dz\right)dP_X \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty g'(z)\underbrace{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{\{x > z\}}dP_X\right)}_{P(X > z)}dz = \int_0^\infty g'(z)P(X > z)dz,
\end{split}
$$

where the second equality is an application of *Fubini's theorem*.

Comment: thank you so much! just a (stupid) question: how did you do this $\int_0^\infty\int_{z}^\infty g'(z)f_X(x)dx dz = \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^xg'(z)f_X(x)dzdx$?

Comment: By reparametrizing the region of integration and changing the order of integration. See the last theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems.