# How does Fubini theorem work for calculating expectation value

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I read that variance of random variable $X$ can be expressed as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}2yP(X>y)\mathrm dy=\int X^{2} \mathrm dP$$
The proof was given as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}2yP(X>y)\mathrm dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int 2y\ 1_{X>y}\ dPdy$$
$$=\int \int_{0}^{\infty}2y\ 1_{X>y}\ dydP=\int \int_{0}^{X}2y\ dydP$$
$$=\int X^{2}\ dP$$

which seemed to make sense. 
However, I also think
$$P(X>y)=\int 1_{X>y}\ dP=\int 1_{(y,\infty)}\ dPX^{-1}$$
Using the same logic,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} 2yP(X>y)\ dy=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int 2y\ 1_{(y,\infty)}\ dPX^{-1}dy$$
but
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} 2y\ 1_{(y,\infty)}\ dy=0$$
since for every $y$, $1_{(y,\infty)}=0$?

I'm sure I made some logical flaw somewhere but I cannot seem to find it.
Please help me figure out resolve this issue.

Comment: Of course your claim is only true if $X \ge 0$ a.s. See proof of more general statement here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3631393/168758.

Comment: $\mathbf 1_{(y..\infty)}$ is not meaningful (what is it indicating? ). You need both an interval *and* a variable to indicate when the *variable* is in the *interval*. Such as $\mathbf 1_{(y..\infty)}(z)$ or  $\mathbf 1_{z\in(y..\infty)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I agree about indicator function is a function defined on a real number that is different from the domain of y. It seems like Fubini's thereom is saying that I can take integral of that indicator with respect y, which I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula and  the first proof are both wrong . For a positive random variable $X$ the correct formula is $\int_0^{\infty} P(X>y)dy=EX$ and not $\int_0^{\infty} yP(X>y)dy=EX$.

EDIT: For the revised version of the question note that you are messing up symbols. $P(X>y)=\int 1_{(y,\infty)}(z)dP\circ X^{-1} (z)$ and use of an extra variable here is important. You will not have $1_{(y,\infty)}(y)$ but $1_{(y,\infty)}(z)$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have edited to make the problem to variance, not expectation values.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply.
I think you are right that $1_{(y,\infty)}$ is not a function of y, but then what does $\int_{0}^{\infty} 1_({y, \infty)}\ dy$ mean? How can I derive $\int X^{2}\ dP$ from this?

Comment: @sharkbear $\int_0^{\infty} 2y P(X>y)dy=\int_0^{\infty} \int 1_{(y,\infty)}(z)dzdP\circ X^{-1}(z)dy=\int \int_0^{z} 2y dydP\circ X^{-1}(z)=\int z^{2}dP\circ X^{-1}(z) =EX^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense!